# Расчет стоимости доставки (вместо начальной точки использовать ближайшую точку из полигона) Яндекс API

Tags: javascript, php, java, яндекс-доставка

сломал себе голову в попытках настроить песочницу от Яндекса. Суть проблемы сделать так, чтобы расчет стоимости доставки шел он КАД до точки выбраной клиентом.

```
      /*routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({
    fromEnabled: false,
    from: 'Начальная точка'
 });*/
```

Есть точки полигона КАД СПБ, может кто подскажет как реализовать, чтоб начальная точка считалась ближайшая к клиенту и от нее строился маршрут и считалась стоимость ?